# Why select tag does not load items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im not getting errors, is just that the select tag is not displaying the option even if the list have them, here is my viewmodel code:

```
public class grupoCRUDModel
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string NIS { set; get; }
    public DateTime FeAcceso { get; set; }
    public invmtolinea Linea { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<invmtolinea> Lineas { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my datamodel code:

```
public class invmtolinea
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximo de 100 caracteres por nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nis { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime feacceso { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller action code:

```
    public IActionResult Editar(int id)
    {
        var grupo = _grupos.GetById(id);
        var lineas = _lineas.GetAll();
        var model = new grupoCRUDModel
        {
            Codigo = grupo.id,
            Nombre = grupo.nombre,
            Linea = grupo.Linea,
            Lineas = lineas
        };
        return PartialView("form", model);
    }
```

And here is my view code, which is a partial to load the edit view for an "grupo" model item:

```
@model libraryDemo.Models.Grupo.grupoCRUDModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar</h4>
</div>
<form asp-controller="Grupo" asp-action="Actualizar" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Codigo" class="hidden" />

        <input asp-for="Codigo" class="hidden" />

        <label asp-for="Nombre"></label>
        <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Nombre"></span> <br />

        <label asp-for="Linea"></label>
        <select asp-for="Linea" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Lineas,"id","nombre"))" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you should add a property to your view model that is `List<invmtolinea>` and use a <select> for Linea and provide the list property name for the values.

Comment: Ok, I´ll do that!

Comment: still not working, im getting a cannot convert implicitly error

Comment: make your list property a `public SelectList` or maybe `List<SelectListItem>` instead

Comment: Im trying to do that, but im not sure how to fill the selectlist

Comment: Action working correctly now with the new List<SelectListItem> but the items are not displayed in the view, im not getting any error also, so not sure why the item are not added to the <select> in the view